# Python: Instantiate class B within a class A instantiation, <class A name> object has no attribute <class B attribute>

Tags: python, class, attributes, instantiation

Python:
I'm using the requests module to work with an API and I'm looking at using classes. I'm getting an attribute error:

**apic.py module:** (class A)

```
import requests
import json

class Ses:

    def __init__(self):
        self = requests.Session() 
        self.headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        print(self.headers)

    def login(self, cname, uname, pword):
        res = self.post( 'https://api.dynect.net/REST/Session/', params = {'customer_name': cname, 'user_name': uname, 'password': pword} ) 
        self.headers.update({'Auth-Token': json.loads(res.text)['data']['token']})
        print( json.loads(res.text)['msgs'][0]['INFO'], '\n' )
        return json.loads(res.text)
```

---

**script:**

```
import requests
import apic

sesh = apic.Ses()

print(sesh.login())
```

- AttributeError: 'Ses' object has no attribute 'post'

  ---

If I remove the call to login() from apic:

```
sesh = apic.Ses()
```

I can see it prints self.headers (sesh.headers) just fine:

- {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

So it seems my syntax is the script is the issue.

.Session is a class in requests (class B)

.post and .headers are functions in the Session class.

My questions:

If I'm instantiating class B in class A instantiation, how should I be calling attributes of class B.

Should I just not be attempting this? (I'm looking at using classes in this way to clean up my script, it's not something I necessarily need to do.)

Comment: `self = requests.Session() ` Never assign to `self`. That doesn't work.

Comment: Either inherit (`class Ses(requests.Session):`) or compose (`self.session = requests.Session()`); the latter will probably be easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just assign to `self`. That's just a local variable within the `__init__` method.

I don't know why you want to do that anyway. Instead you should be defining the session as an attribute of the instance:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.session = requests.Session() 
    self.session.headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    print(self.session.headers)

def login(self, cname, uname, pword):
    res = self.session.post('https://api.dynect.net/REST/Session/', params = {'customer_name': cname, 'user_name': uname, 'password': pword} ) 
    ...
```